# new to Perl - CSV - find a string and print all numbers in that column

Tags: perl, csv

I've got a bunch of data in a CSV file, first row is all strings (all text and underscores), all subsequent rows are filled with numbers relating to said strings.

I'm trying to parse through the first line and find particular strings, remember which column that string was in, and then go through the rest of the file and get the data in the same column. I need to do this to three strings.

I've been using Text::CSV but I can't figure out how to get it to increment a counter until it finds the string in the first line and then go to the next line, get the data from that same column, etc. etc. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
while (<CSV>) {
    if ($csv->parse($data)) {
        my @field = $csv->fields;
        my $count = 0;
            for $column (@field) {
            print ++$count, " => ", $column, "\n";
        }
    } else {
        my $err = $csv->error_input;
        print "Failed to parse line: $err";
    }
}
```

Since $data is in line 1, it prints "1 $data" 25 times (# of lines in CSV file). How do I get it to remember which column it found $data in? Also, since I know all of the strings are in line 1, how do I get it to only parse through line 1, find all of the strings in @data, and then parse through the rest of the file, grabbing data from the necessary columns and putting it into a matrix or array of arrays?
Thanks for the help!

edit: I realized my questions were a bit poorly phrased. I don't know how to get the column number from CSV. How is this done? 
Also, once I've got the column number, how do I tell it CSV to run through the subsequent lines and grab data from only that column?

Comment: "How do I get it to remember which column it found `$data` in?" Store it in a variable (that you define outside of your `while` loop).

Comment: Poorly phrased question, sorry. Storing something in a variable isn't the problem - how do I get the column number in the first place?

Comment: Figure out the index of `@fields` in which your element lies. Looping is sufficient (although there are more idiomatic ways).

Comment: That's what I'm asking how to do... I don't know how to find the index of @fields at which $data was found.

Comment: Loop through `0..$#fields` and set `$_` equal to the index variable of your choice if `$data` is matched.

Comment: I don't follow. @field is filled in only when the string is found, so it's only going to be an array of one...

Comment: No, when you call the `fields` method on `$csv`, an array of values is returned (and, in your code, assigned to `@fields`). If you haven't matched `$data`, yet, then iterate through `@fields` (via `foreach my $i(0..$#fields)`), figure out if there's a data match, and if there is, assign `$i` to the variable that you're using to store the column position.

Comment: Running this:
    while(<CSV>) {
        if($csv->parse($data)) {
            my @field = $csv->fields;
            print @field."\n";
        }
    }
Gives me a ton of 1s, so I don't quite see how I can iterate through an array of one.

Comment: That's because you're calling `@field` in a scalar context. Take a look at `perldoc perldata`, and at my answer below.

Comment: can you please provide a SMALL sample dataset and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({binary=>1});

my $thing_to_match = "blah";
my $matched_index;
my @stored_data = ();

while(my $row= $csv->getline(*DATA)) #grabs lines below __DATA__ 
                                     #(near the end of the script)
{
    my @fields = @$row;

    #If we haven't found the matched index, yet, search for it.
    if(not defined $matched_index)
    {
        foreach my $i(0..$#fields)
        {
            $matched_index = $i if($fields[$i] eq $thing_to_match);
        }
    }

    #NOTE: We're pushing a *reference* to an array!
    #Look at perldoc perldata
    push @stored_data,\@fields;
}

die "Column for '$thing_to_match' not found!" unless defined $matched_index;

foreach my $row(@stored_data)
{
    print $row->[$matched_index] . "\n";
}


__DATA__
stuff,more stuff,yet more stuff
"yes, this thing, is one item",blah,blarg
1,2,3
```

The output is:

```
more stuff
blah
2
```

Comment: Do not do my `$line = <>; @values = $csv->parse()` ... this is wrong for any csv file that could potentially have newlines. See the [Text::CSV docs](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to write up a full example, but I wrote a module that might help you do this. [Tie::Array::CSV](http://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aCSV) uses some magic to make your csv file act like a Perl array of arrayrefs. In this way you can use your knowledge of Perl to interact with the file.

A word of warning though! One benefit of my module is that it is read/write. Since you only want read, be careful not to assign to it!